# How to exclude items matching text pattern inside for loop?

Tags: python

I am pulling some images with scrapy into a python list. There are some images which are placeholders and are idenifiable by the URL. So I would like to check via regex on a specific string and if matched skip this image.

```
images = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content').extract()[0:3]

>>> images
['https://www.example.com/image/8a/53/ba/WARas201B-BA0723.jpg']

image_urls = [x.re_first('^((?!Demo_600x600.*).)*$') for x in images]
```

This unfortunatelly does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 1, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're_first'
```

How can I exclude images with `Demo_600x600` in their name from pulling into the the list "images" at best?

Comment: What do you hope/imagine `re_first` should do? The Python `re` library uses `re.match` to match a regular expression against the start of a string.

Comment: I want to exclude all items where the URL will match the given pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to use a regex seems like overkill here.

```
image_urls = [x for x in images if not 'Demo_600x600' in x]
```

If you insist on using a regular expression, try

```
image_urls = [x for x in images if not re.search('Demo_600x600', x)]
```

Comment: will this also work for urls with that string in the middle of the URL? e.g. 86348-Demo_600x600.jpg

Comment: Your requirements were unlclear, to put it mildly. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would it also be possible to exclude it in the first statement where i pull the images from the source or do I need to go though that for loop?

Comment: I don't know enough XPath to tell off hand. I'm guessing it could be possible. Ask a new question (but review [the guidance](/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question it is possible not to regex.

```
images = ["image1.png",
          "image2.png",
          "image3.png",
          "image_demo.png",
          "image4.png",
          "image_example.png",
          "image_demo.png"]

for image in images:
    if not "demo" in image:
        # do your thing here
        print (image)
```

This returns:

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
image4.png
image_example.png
```

If you have a list of things you want to exclude you could do something like this.

```
excludes = ["demo", "example"]

for image in images:
    for exclude in excludes:
        if exclude in image:
            break
    else:
        # do your thing here
        print (image)
```

This returns:

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
image4.png
```